# Codeigniter cannot run a loop

Tags: php, codeigniter

My model returns array with "user ids" and I want to run loop for each of those user ids but I get errors **"Undefined variable: users"** and **"Invalid argument supplied for foreach()"**. Could you please check what is wrong with my controller code.

**My Model:**

```
 public function get_user_id($post_id){

    $this->db->select('user_id');
    $this->db->from('comments');   
    $this->db->where('post_id', $post_id);

    $query = $this->db->get();

if ($query && $query->num_rows() >= 1){ 

return $query->result();
    }    
     else {
    return false;
    }

   }
```

**My controller:**

```
$this->model_a->get_user_id($post_id);
$data["users"] = $this->model_a->get_user_id($post_id);         

foreach($users as $user){

$user_id = $user['user_id'];
//loop code 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

$data["users"] = $this->model_a->get_user_id($post_id);

> foreach($data["users"] as $user){
>
> $user_id = $user['user_id']; //loop code
>
> }

There is no variable called $users

Comment: Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

Comment: @EducateYourself use result_array() insted of result()

Comment: Thanks Roni and Shijin. I have combined your answers and it works now.

Answer (score 1):

```
   $this->model_a->get_user_id($post_id);
$data["users"] = $users = $this->model_a->get_user_id($post_id);         

foreach($users as $user){

$user_id = $user['user_id'];
//loop code 
}
```

$users must be defined.

Answer (score 1):

try -

in the model -

```
if ($query && $query->num_rows() >= 1){ 
   return $query->result_array();
} else {
   return false;
}
```

in controller -

```
$data["users"] = $this->model_a->get_user_id($post_id);

foreach($users as $user){
     $user_id = $user['user_id'];
     //loop code 
}
```